# Execute Query only if a Oracle DB Table Exists

Tags: oracle

> Hi Database Experts,
>
> Could anyone of you please suggest how I go about executing the
> following SQL Query against a Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition
> Release 12.2.0.1.0 Database. I am running this query on a daily basis
> for some reporting. The below query is called by a BASH Script which
> passes it all the variables including dates. The view "See &2" in my
> query is dynamically created each day and based on various factors may
> or may not be created on a particular day. But when created it does
> follow a standard name with the date stamp. Based on that I am looping
> through each day's date. This would work only on the days the view is
> created but on the days when it is not created the query errors out
> with a "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" Error and corrupts
> the report. How do I add a condition to my query such that it executes
> only if the only if the view exists or even if there is a way I could ignore it by "TURNING OFF" an option in the select query that would also work for me

```
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE FAILURE
SET linesize 250
SET pagesize 50000
SET newpage none
SET trimspool ON
SET feedback OFF verify OFF tab OFF echo OFF termout OFF underline OFF heading OFF
column "Data Center" format a10
column "Application ID" format a8
column "Order Date" format a10
column "System Date" format a12
spool &1 append
SELECT
'&3' "Data Center",
APPLICATION_ID "Application ID",
SUM(NUMBER_OF_TASKS) "No. of Tasks",
'&4' "Order Date",
'&5' "System Date"
FROM
(
SELECT APPLICATION_ID,NUMBER_OF_TASKS FROM
(
SELECT CASE WHEN TIME_ZONE != ' ' AND ODATE = '&4' THEN APPLICATION ELSE NULL END AS APPLICATION_ID,
COUNT(CASE WHEN TIME_ZONE != ' ' AND ODATE = '&4' THEN APPLICATION ELSE NULL END) AS NUMBER_OF_TASKS
FROM &2 WHERE TASK_TYPE NOT LIKE '%SMART Table%' AND TASK_TYPE NOT LIKE '%Sub-Table%'
GROUP BY CASE WHEN TIME_ZONE != ' ' AND ODATE = '&4' THEN APPLICATION ELSE NULL END) TIMEZONE_JOBS
GROUP BY APPLICATION_ID,NUMBER_OF_TASKS
UNION
SELECT APPLICATION_ID,NUMBER_OF_TASKS FROM
(
SELECT APPLICATION AS APPLICATION_ID,
COUNT(APPLICATION) AS NUMBER_OF_TASKS
FROM &2 WHERE TIME_ZONE = ' ' AND TASK_TYPE NOT LIKE '%SMART Table%' AND TASK_TYPE NOT LIKE '%Sub-Table%'
GROUP BY APPLICATION) NON_TIMEZONE_JOBS
GROUP BY APPLICATION_ID,NUMBER_OF_TASKS
)
WHERE NUMBER_OF_TASKS != '0'
GROUP BY APPLICATION_ID ORDER BY APPLICATION_ID;
spool OFF
EXIT;
```

Comment: please remove everything from your code that is not relevant for your problem

Comment: You can query the dictionary view `USER_VIEWS`  to check if the view exists and execute an alternative query variant depending on the result.

Comment: @mustaccio - Can you share a sample of what you are suggesting ?
Perhaps try editing the query I have provided if you'd like

Answer (score 2):

> How do I add a condition to my query such that it executes only if the only if the view exists

You can't. The SQL statement will fail to Parse well before you get to the `WHERE` clause.

The decision to run/not run needs to be handled in the BASH script by checking the exit code of the script ( `$?` )

There are a few ways of doing this. All involve testing "is this a real table?" separately.

**USER_VIEWS**

*credit: mostacciio*

Check the data dictionary view `USER_VIEWS` if the view actually exists.

Example

```
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE FAILURE
variable view_name varchar2(256 byte)
execute select a.view_name into :view_name from user_views a where a.view_name = '&2';
```

**DBMS_ASSERT**

Use the `DBMS_ASSERT` package to validate the existence of a DB object.

IMO -  you should always use this package to validate your input for DB Objects when dealing with dynamic SQL.

Example

```
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE FAILURE
variable view_name varchar2(256 byte)
execute :view_name = dbms_assert.sql_object_name( '&2' );
```

**REST service**

I would probably set up a REST service (ORDS) that returns "yes/no" and call that with something like `curl`. BASH script will parse the results and act accordingly.

If there was a hint that you'll have >1 views to process on a single run, I'd go this route as the single REST Service can provide a space separated list of view names (which BASH can easily parse with a loop).

Comment: Thanks . Could you possibly post a sample of the DBMS_ASSERT option you are suggesting

Comment: @delhivenky - answer enhanced with example code.

Comment: I am testing your example code and getting a "Bind Variable "view_name" is NOT DECLARED" error